# How to update the specified number of documents in mongo-driver-go just like mysql `update table set filed = dxx limit 50 `

Tags: mongodb, go

How to update the specified number of documents in Mongo just like mysql

```
update table set filed = dxx limit 50
```

use this go version mongo-driver
 https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo

Answer (score 0):

Using Mongo DB Shell, We can use this query:
    `db.collection.find().limit(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_YOU_WANT_TO_UPDATE).forEach( 
    function (element) { 
    element.newField = newData; 
    db.collection.save(element); 
    });`

To implement the same thing using mongo go driver,

> 1.Fetch the required records with Collection.find() Method using limit in find options
>   2.Use the cursor of find query and Append the required Update queries in []mongo.WriteModel 
>   3.Execute collection.BulkWrite() Method with []mongo.WriteModel Slice as input and use the BulkWriteResult returned.

Comment: what is the mongodb driver addr?  i be limit this driver https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo

Comment: this is fetch then update, it is 1+n number command? mongo is not like mysql one command to do it ?

Comment: Yes this is for the same mongo go driver you have mentioned in your query

Comment: Either connect to a mongo shell via go program and execute the query. Using mongo go driver, a for each method along with find is not available last time I checked. May be you can create a jira ticket in the mongo go portal and they will introduce this features in the further updates.